# chef powershell_script console output

Tags: chef-infra

Hi i am trying to read a log-file and print it back in my cook book using poswershell_script but it is not printing anything but says completed .. . below is a sample script that i am trying to use
Env : Windows server 2012
Chef Client, version 12.4.3

```
powershell_script 'Print Log File' do
  code '$logFilePath = "C:\log.txt"
Get-Content $logFilePath | foreach {Write-Output $_}' 
end
```

I also tried the below which did not work

```
  powershell_script "TestConsoleOutput" do
       code 'Write-host "---------------> Writing to the console" '
    end
```

I found the same question out there but i don't see it answered...

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the trick. Use the flag `live_stream true` to your powershell_script resource.** This will print all your powershell logs live when the `powershell_script` resoiurce block is executed.

```
powershell_script 'Print Log File' do
  code '$logFilePath = "C:\log.txt"
  Get-Content $logFilePath | foreach {Write-Output $_}'
  live_stream true
end
```

Also,

```
powershell_script "TestConsoleOutput" do
  code 'Write-host "---------------> Writing to the console" '
  live_stream true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by print back to your cookbook. This prints the content of the log file to console

```
ruby_block 'print output' do
    only_if { ::File.exists?('C:\\log.txt') }
    block do
        print "\n"
        File.read('C:\\log.txt')
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for that ... I have a recipe which install a software but writes the log to file .. now i need to print that back on the console in the same chef recipe.. or at least pass the log file path so that i can print it back to console..

Comment: Use `Chef::Log.<level>` instead of print as it would follow the a log location defined into `chef-client.rb`

Comment: is there a way log from  powershell_script...  I tried using write-host write-output .. no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. To get your powershell output displayed from a ruby block,  call '***powershell_out***' library as shown below. Try this and post your result here.

> ```
> require "chef/mixin/powershell_out"
> ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut)
>
>
> pscode = <<-EOH
>   $logFilePath = "C:\log.txt"
>   Get-Content $logFilePath | foreach { Write-Output $_ }
> EOH
>
>
> ruby_block 'Print Log File' do
>   block do
>     cmnd = powershell_out!(pscode)
>     if !cmnd.stderr.empty?
>       puts cmnd.stderr
>     else
>       puts cmnd.stdout
>     end
>   end
>   action :run
> end
> ```